# How to download all files related to a publication from figshare, based on the doi number?

Tags: api, download, doi, rfigshare

I want to fetch the whole db of a publication from FigShare, possibly using a script.
But could not find how to get the url of the files associate to the DOI citation of the publication.

How to do that?

--

Consider this research:

- https://figshare.com/collections/An_annotated_dataset_of_Egyptian_fruit_bat_vocalizations_across_varying_contexts_and_during_vocal_ontogeny/3666502

See that there is a DOI for citing the material, displaying the article ID and version:

- https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.c.3666502.v2

So, referring to the API in Figshare, I try:

- https://docs.figshare.com/

I try:

- https://api.figshare.com/v2/articles/3666502

but the article is missing.

Trying to download all of the files - wav and the CSV database referring to the DOI:

- https://api.figshare.com/v2/file/download/3666502

but no files.

Looking on the webpage I see in the FigShare page that each collection has its own filenumber. But there are 60+ collections, and numbering seems not progressive either.

How can I find all of the url of the materials referring to the DOI publications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Figshare parlance what you are looking at is a collection and the files that you want are the articles in that collection.

So, what you should try is:
https://api.figshare.com/v2/collections/3666502/articles

You can set the page size to 70 so that you get all 65 entries in one request instead of having to page through them:
https://api.figshare.com/v2/collections/3666502/articles?page_size=70

Then take the url of each article and retrieve it, such as:
https://api.figshare.com/v2/articles/5212192

In that response you will find the download_url which will let you directly retrieve the actual file.

Comment: presicely that! Thank you @dagrenzer